# Is there a method in python to capture an image and identify its dimensions

Tags: python, image-processing

Im looking for a method in python to read an image and identify its dimensions.
Also to read an image and reproduce the same image.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the Pil librairy for the dimension

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('filename.png')
print 'width: %d - height: %d' % im.size # returns (width, height) tuple
```

And for the copy it is even simpler, use:

```
Image.copy()
```

It copies this image. Use this method if you wish to paste things into an image, but still retain the original.

Answer (score 0):

Using OpenCV, you can read an Image. OpenCV `imread` method is used to read image and it is stored numpy ndarray. You can get the dimensions using the size property.

eg:

```
 img = cv2.imread('/path/to/image.png')
 dimensions = img.shape
```